# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un spinner muestre la lista pero no permita seleccionar los componentes?

Tags: android

Hice este código basado en un tutorial de youtube para la implementacion de un spinner. La diferencia es que yo quiero que se despliegue la info pero que NO sea seleccionable.

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sp01"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitulo"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">
    </Spinner>

</RelativeLayout>
```

array.xml

```
Array.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="opciones">
        <item>Opcion 1</item>
        <item>Opcion 2</item>
        <item>Opcion 3</item>
        <item>Opcion 4</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```

y activity_main.xml

```
package saeta.ilspinner;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner opciones;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        opciones = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp01);
        opciones.setClickable(false);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        opciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Super importante: Para lograr mi objetivo he hecho las siguientes opciones pero ninguna funcionó:

poner android:clickable="false"
y opciones.setClickable(false);

Answer (score 2):

Existe una forma y sobre-escribiendo los metodos `isEnabled` y `areAllItemsEnabled`

```
class MenuAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> {

    public MenuAdapter(
        Context context, int textViewResId, CharSequence[] strings) {
        super(context, textViewResId, strings);
    }

    public static MenuAdapter createFromResource(
       Context context, int textArrayResId, int textViewResId) {

       Resources      resources = context.getResources();
       CharSequence[] strings   = resources.getTextArray(textArrayResId);

        return new MenuAdapter(context, textViewResId, strings);
    }

    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Deberas cambiar

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
opciones.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Por esto :

```
MenuAdapter adapter = MenuAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.opciones, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
opciones.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Tambien puedes probar con `setFocusable(false)` y `setClickable(false)` ojo que debe ser por item y no por la lista como creo que lo estabas haciendo.

```
getItem(1).setFocusable(false);
getItem(1).setClickable(false);
.....
```

Comment: este código va en el mainactivity.java  o en un .java diferente?

Comment: Si vas a ocuparlo en otras activitys es mejor que lo agregues en otro archivo